# Does the single quote on iOS have different value than on MacOS?

Tags: macos, ios

I notice that any of my passwords that has single quotes (`'`) aren't accepted on some websites if I type it on Safari. If I use my Mac and Chrome for the same websites, they're accepted. Have anyone experienced this?

Comment: I have noticed this as well in a music application I use; within the iOS app I get a ' - but when editing on the Mac I get a smart quote. Sorry I don't have an fix type answer for you, but I avoid single quotes in unseen fields (ie passwords) ...

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have Smart Punctuation on your iOS device turned OFF.  That should normally guarantee a U+0027 ascii apostrophe.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to the question at the top of Q&A, but hopefully still useful.

Long press on the key that exists on the "number" keyboard in the position of <kbd>M</kbd>. You will see the option immediately above the key is the apostrophe.

[image]